# How to calculate integrals lilke $\int \frac{(2x+3)^C}{\sqrt x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

For sufficiently large values of C, say 100, how do I go about evaluating this sort of integral:

$$\int\frac{(2x+3)^{100}}{\sqrt x}dx$$

Of course, one could, in theory, just expand the expression with the binomial theorem, but I'm looking for a faster method. I tried substitution but I don't think it's even possible in this case.

Comment: Where did such an integral arise?

Comment: @ZacharySelkI Well my textbook has the following exercise:$\int \frac{(2x+3)^2}{\sqrt x}$ which is easy to expand, but I want to know if there's some generalization which can be made for any exponent

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} (2 x+3)^C \, dx=2\cdot 3^C \sqrt{x} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-C;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{3} (2 x)\right)$$
Where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is not the most general one, due to the expression in the brackets, but we can mind as follows.

Set

$$(2x +3)^C = z$$

Hence reversing the substitution:

$$dx = \frac{ z^{1/C - 1}}{2C}\ dz ~~~~~~~~~~~ x = \frac{z^{1/C} - 3}{2}$$

Hence your integral becomes

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2C}\int \frac{z^{1/C}}{(z^{1/C}-3)^{1/2}} dz$$

Which is known to be an integral in terms of the HyperGeometric Function.

The final result is

$$3\sqrt{2}\frac{ z \left(\sqrt{9-3 z^{1/C}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},C;C+1;\frac{z^{1/C}}{3}\right)+z^{1/C}-3\right)}{(2 C+1) \sqrt{z^{1/C}-3}}$$

Where $_2F_1$ stands for the HyperGeometric function.

**More on HGF**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

Comment: It's wrong. If $(2 x+3)^c=z$ then $$x=1/2 (-3 + z^{(1/c)})$$ and so $$\int \frac{\left(\sqrt{2} z\right) z^{\frac{1}{c}-1}}{(2 c) \sqrt{z^{1/c}-3}} \, dz$$ which is not so simpler than the starting integral

Comment: @Raffaele Aye, I noticed my stupid error, indeed I'm editing :D